# How to install and configure memchached for Geonode 3.2 installation on Windows 64, Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, memcached

The Geonode 3.2 guide spells out the below procedures/steps for memchached configuration, any idea on  the link or url where I can download memcached for windows 64, I am having a hard time locating the necessary files on the internet for Windows 64 bit that I can then run locally as indicated below.

Install and configure “memcached”

```
sudo apt install memcached
sudo systemctl start memcached
sudo systemctl enable memcached

workon <your_geonode_venv_name>
cd /<full_path_to_the_geonode_source_code>

sudo apt install libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev

pip install pylibmc==1.6.1
pip install sherlock==0.3.2

sudo systemctl restart supervisor.service
sudo systemctl status supervisor.service
```

The below error suggest the above solution, that I am having a hard time solving.

After downloading and installing Microsoft Build in Tools, I run into a subsequent error message when pip installing GeoNode 3.2 requirement text file. The error suggest installing libmemcached however I cannot find any tutorial on how to do the installation. Any idea on how to solve this error or address  this issue?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-emqrxyfb'
       cwd: C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\
  Complete output (28 lines):
  C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\setup.py:98: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
    with open("README.rst", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
  C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\setup.py:100: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
    with open("src/pylibmc-version.h", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\autoconf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\consts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\pools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  running build_ext
  building '_pylibmc' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DUSE_ZLIB -IC:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include -Ic:\users\lenis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\lenis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
  _pylibmcmodule.c
  C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\src\_pylibmcmodule.h(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylibmc




ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-frvsks6r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include\site\python3.7\pylibmc'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\setup.py:98: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
      with open("README.rst", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\setup.py:100: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
      with open("src/pylibmc-version.h", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\autoconf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\consts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\pools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    running build_ext
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DUSE_ZLIB -IC:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include -Ic:\users\lenis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\lenis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
    _pylibmcmodule.c
    C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ksxffint\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\src\_pylibmcmodule.h(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ksxffint\\pylibmc_ad3f721e28de4f8db05b79ba5c8f675c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-frvsks6r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include\site\python3.7\pylibmc' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: If you are installing GeoNode in ubuntu (i think that you are using the WSL) there is no need to install the stuff on windows. Just use geonode in the subsystem

Comment: I am installing GeoNode for the first time and doing it on Windows but its complex. I have not used Ubuntu before. I learned however packages such as Pylibmc,Sherlock and wsgi only works on linux but part of the geonode recquirement.txt file. That then mean I need to install Ubuntu on Windows and install GeoNode there? This will save me time comparing to doing it on windows? I have not used Ubuntu either however I can follow youtube tutorials.

Comment: I work with geonode, so my suggestion is to install it on ubuntu if you need to develop with it. If you need to use it as a user, you can simply use the Docker-compose file available and let it run. You can install ubuntu in the wsl (Windows subsystem Linux). Microsoft has plenty of doc related to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
To build with docker (after installing it) Run the docker-build.sh file and wait. It should works without issues

Answer (score 0):

GeoNode is set to run on a Linux environment only.

If you want to run it on windows, you may try to use [Cartoview Windows Installer](https://cartoview.net/) which has GeoNode configured to run on Windows.

Cartoview is an extension of GeoNode visualizing the layers and maps in geospatial apps.